# Passing a reference when the app is not running

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a database whose reference I am saving in a static variable. So when the app is running everything works fine but when the app is not running the reference also turns out to be null as the variables are not available now. So how do i save the reference of the database even when the app is not running because i want to receive the GCM notifications and based on that i want to make an entry into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply created a new Object reference and that worked for me 
Thanx everyone

Answer (score 2):

Your code processing the notification also has a reference to a `Context`. You can use the `Context` to initialize your database connection if one is not already initialized.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Content Provider for accessing the database, that way you do not need to have any reference and you won't have this problem.

Answer (score -1):

you have many storage options:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

In my opinion best and fast way would be use SharedPreferences